# Enumerate in range

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have two numpy arrays (`my_numpy_array_1` and `my_numpy_array_2`). 
I want to iterate over both, get out the corresponding indices and values.

My problem is that I need to set the start index when iterating over `my_numpy_array_2`, if `idx_data_2` is greater than 0.

How can I enumerate in range, like the code below (but this code example below doesn't work)?

```
idx = 0

for idx_data_1, val_data_1 in np.ndenumerate(my_numpy_array_1):

    # How can I do this using a new start index (idx), when re-entering for loop?
    idx_data_2, val_data_2 = (min(enumerate(range (idx, my_numpy_array_2.size, 1), 
                              key=lambda x: abs(x[1] - val_data_1)))


    if idx_data_2 > 0:

        idx = idx_data_2 + 1
```

Comment: If these are 1d arrays, it may be easier to do this kind of iteration with lists, possibly with `while` loops if you need to play with indices in a way the `for` doesn't allow.

Comment: Yes, the two arrays are 1D. I need a really efficient way to iterate over the two numpy arrays, because the two arrays are quite big.

Comment: `efficient` and `iterate` don't belong in the same sentence, at least not when talking about `numpy`!  Lists are faster if you can't figure out a whole-array methods of do the job.